# Displaying retina graphics correctly that aren't from the image assets

Tags: ios, xcode, retina-display

I am a little confused about how retina images work in Xcode. I understand that if I use the image assets I can specify the 2* and 3* images for retina and iPhone6+ respectively and I just reference the image and Xcode does the rest. What about if I am using an image that isn't from the assets though? Say for example I am storing images of a users profile picture on the server, if I had a 70*70pt profile picture would I  just set the image as a 140*140px one for the retina display? For the 6+ would I do the same? Set a 210*210 one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just include images in your project like

1. profile.png (70 X 70)normal
2. profile@2x.png (140 X 140) for retina
3. profile@3x.png (210 X 210) for iphone 6+ devices

and use it normally in your project.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView imageNamed:@"profile.png"];
```

this will have the same effect as in assets.

Comment: what about if I am using an UIImageView made in the interface builder? Would I keep this size as 70*70?

Comment: @Kex Your UIImageView is not measured in pixels in interface builder. It's measured in points. So a 70pt x 70pt UIImageView on an iPhone 6 is actually 140x140 pixels due to the retina display, and 210x 210 pixels on an iPhone 6 Plus. The naming convention's mentioned in this answer are the easiest way to go about handling the different resolutions for different devices.

Comment: I mean in my interface builder I want a 70*70pt image view, so for this to work properly for all resolutions I include all the images with the naming convention as above and leave it as 70*70 and just use UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView imageNamed:@"profile.png"]; That right?

Comment: @Kex exactly. You're just creating these images for resolution purposes.

Comment: thanks a lot guys, cleared that up for me. I usually just work with vector images so wasn't sure. cheers

Comment: @Daniel Thanks friend for the support.

Answer (score 0):

As per my personal experience, when you upload an image to the server it is saved as it is.
For e.g: A 70*70 px image would be saved as 70*70 px.

Now, you have 2 options.

1. When you fetch that image using the app it is downloaded as 70*70 only and the image is displayed in your UIImageView as it is. Then, i would suggest you to keep your UIImageView size as 35*35 to keep the image crisp.
2. Upload 210*210 px image and then download the image using the app and then create 2 more copies of it. One with 70*70 and other with 140*140 dimension.

I would suggest going for a middle approach (140*140 px image and display it in 70*70 px UIImageView) if you can compromise a bit with the image quality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do;

• Have your UIImageView at the @1x size (i.e. 70x70).

• Download the correct resolution asset you need (70x70 for @1x, 140x140 for @2x etc.)

• Create the UIImage using `- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data scale:(CGFloat)scale` or similar methods, passing in the correct scale.